# What is the inferred type of a function argument with a default value but no type annotation? How about a variable initialized as 'None'?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

What is the type (in the sense of type annotations, not `type()`) of variables and parameters that come without a type annotation but with an initial value? E.g.,

```
foo = 2
bar = False
baz = MyClass()
bazz = None
```

Judging from the [Mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_inference_and_annotations.html#type-inference) [docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#redefinitions-with-incompatible-types) and [example code in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#the-any-type), `foo`, `bar`, `baz` would *currently* be assigned the types `int`, `False` and `MyClass`. Has this been standardized anywhere, though? And what about `bazz`? And what about

```
def my_func(param1 = 2, param2 = False): 
    ...
```

? Would a type checker enforce arguments passed to `my_func` to be of type `int` and `bool`, respectively?

Note that I'm not that much interested in the *status quo*, e.g. the current implementation of type checkers like Mypy. Rather, I'm wondering whether the answer to my questions has been standardized anywhere. Unfortunately, [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) does not seem to say anything about this, apart from:

> Type checkers are expected to attempt to infer as much information as necessary.

…but it is unclear what this really means in the above situation. (After all, `param1 = 2` might only be the default value and its actual type might be more complex in reality.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Question 1: What is the inferred type of a function argument with a default value but no type annotation?

In 2017, [Guido van Rossum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/818274/guido-van-rossum), the creator of the Python language, suggested changing [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) to specify that function arguments would infer their types from default values.

However, as of October 2020, PEP 484 states in section ["The `Any` type](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-any-type):

> A function parameter without an annotation is assumed to be annotated with `Any`.

In the discussion points below from [**mypy issue #3090**](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3090) (*Infer argument type from default value*), Jukka reinforces the fact that default values do not change the default behavior of inferring unannotated parameters as having type `Any`.

[Jukka Lehtosalo](https://github.com/JukkaL) wrote:

> Mypy follows [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). **A function parameter without an annotation is the same as having an `Any` annotation, and there is no exception for default values.** Here is some rationale for this:
>
> - Often the default argument is not enough to infer a type. For example, `None` doesn't give enough context. With the current rules this doesn't pose a difficulty.
> - The default argument may not be enough to infer the correct type. For example, if the default is `''` in Python 2, the correct type could well be `Union[str, unicode]`. If the default is `0`, the correct type might well be `float`. If the programmer understands the rules for type inference they could override the default type with an annotation as needed, but this would add some extra complexity.
> - The default value could be a complex expression such as a function call, and thus the type may not [be] obvious from just the default value. Having an annotation makes code like this easier to read.
> - If a function has no annotation at all, then the argument type would have to be `Any` anyway. The current rule makes this consistent across functions with no annotations and functions with partial annotations.
>
> It all boils down to the current rule being simple and obvious, and in practice it doesn't feel much of a burden to add a few extra : `int` annotations. There is no deep technical reason for the current rule, though it makes type inference easier for mypy.

Then [Guido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/818274/guido-van-rossum) responded:

> OTOH most of those also apply to regular assignments, and there the rule is that
>
> `x = 0`
>
> infers type `int` for `x`. In practice this is very common and useful and only occasionally needs help. So I think we might use the same rule for default values and the complexity of explaining things wouldn't really change. I'm willing to make this a PEP 484 change if enough people care.

## Question 2: What is the inferred type of a variable initialized as `None`?

When a variable is initialized as `None`, it is directly inferred that the variable is allowed to be explicitly assigned to `None`. If the variable is then later assigned a value, such as:

```
bazz = None
bazz = 42  # type: Optional[int]
```

then the type is inferred to be `Optional[int]`. Since the inferred type of `bazz` is `Optional[int]`, it can later be reassigned `None` without error.

```
bazz = None
bazz = 42
bazz = None  # Okay
```

However, if `bazz` had not been initialized as `None`, then the following would be an error:

```
bazz = 42
bazz = None  # Error: expression has type "None", variable has type "int"
```

## Inferred types of variables initialized without type annotations

[PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) does not explicitly discuss inferring the types of unannotated variables based on the types of their assigned values. However, it can be *inferred from the comments* in the PEP 484 examples, that the types of unannotated variables are indeed inferred based on assignment.

#### Example from PEP 484 section ["Scoping rules for type variables"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#scoping-rules-for-type-variables)

```
T = TypeVar('T')
S = TypeVar('S')
class Foo(Generic[T]):
    def method(self, x: T, y: S) -> S:
        ...

x = Foo()               # type: Foo[int]
y = x.method(0, "abc")  # inferred type of y is str
```

#### Example from PEP 484 section ["Instantiating generic classes and type erasure"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#instantiating-generic-classes-and-type-erasure)

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

class Node(Generic[T]):
    x = None  # type: T # Instance attribute (see below)
    def __init__(self, label: T = None) -> None:
        ...

x = Node('')  # Inferred type is Node[str]
y = Node(0)   # Inferred type is Node[int]
z = Node()    # Inferred type is Node[Any]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this comprehensive answer, Christopher! This was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Just to make sure: Even though Guido said he'd be *willing* to change PEP 484, he so far has not, correct? FWIW, I don't think the situation of default values for parameters is really comparable to the initial values of variables and so I don't think a change of PEP 484 is in order. Default values merely say what the value (and type) of a variable *could potentially be*, whereas an initial value makes a definite statement about what the value (and thus type) of a variable is going to be.

Comment: @balu As of October 2020, PEP 484 has not been modified to require that default function arguments be used for type inference. However, I agree with Guido's point. It will be interesting to see if this change is made at some point in the future. Thank you for the great question!

Comment: Also I just realized that I was wrong and that, as Jutta Lehtosalo says, PEP 484 indeed *does* make a statement about the inferred types of function arguments (even though it doesn't mention default values explicitly): The relevant part is in the [section "The Any type"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-any-type): *A function parameter without an annotation is assumed to be annotated with Any.*

Comment: Just to make sure, though: PEP 484 does *not* say anything about the case of variables with initial values that lack type annotations, correct? (I.e. the case of the variables `foo`, `bar`, `baz` in my example code above.) Currently, this seems to be purely an implementation detail of Mypy. I just extended my original question accordingly to include this point. Would be great if you could include the answer in your post, as well, so that future visitors will be able to see everything at once! :)

Comment: @balu See updated answer with new section on the inferred types of variables without annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the types situation of this block

```
foo = 2
bar = False
baz = MyClass()
bazz = None
```

they do have types that you could annotate if you want them to be checked. In my experience, there are certain cases where `mypy` manages to infer some types, but usually is because they're being annotated somewhere else "earlier"like in function signatures of attributes in classes or instances.

Thus, the block

```
foo: int = 2
bar: bool = False
baz: MyClass = MyClass()
bazz: Optional[?] = None
```

In the case of `baz` the class itself is a type, so you annotate it with the name of the class.
For `bazz` I left a `?` since you should have an expectation of the type it'll have. Maybe it can be a couple of possible types and use `Union[int, float]` or maybe you don't really know/care and use `Any` as type.

Now, about the function

```
def my_func(param1 = 2, param2 = False): 
    ...
```

If the signature of that function would be annotated, the type checker would tell you if it's being called correctly.

```
def my_func(param1: int = 2, param2: bool = False): 
    ...
```

The type checker is not an enforcer, python continues being a dynamic language. Although there could be tools/libraries that exploit the annotations to do some runtime enforcement of types.

Comment: Thank you for your post, Ignacio! However, it doesn't really answer my question. My question was not, How do I get the type checks working?, nor, What does Mypy do? (I already knew this.) Rather, I was asking whether this behavior of type inference was standardized anywhere.

Comment: Sorry! Well, if you haven't found it in a PEP, most likely the inference part should be tool dependant. Now, keep in mind, that still part of my answer applies as the inference can reliably happen only when there is prior information being from argument annotations, return annotations, or attributes annotations. In my experience, if you don't annotate something, `mypy` will tend to complain.